# Highcharts zIndex of Y-Axis title

Tags: highcharts, title, jscript, gauge

I have a little problem. I use the high charts gauge diagram and the dial covers my title of my y-axis. I tried to solve this problem with the zIndex property for my title, like this:

```
yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Title Y-Axis',
                    y: 20,
                    style: {
                        fontSize:16,
                        zIndex: 3      
                    }
                },
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Does anybody have an idea how I put the title in the foreground so that the dial doesn't cover my title?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `useHTML` parameter as true.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0kdnncvu/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. But the fontsize of my title is now smaller than before, because, I think that the fontSize property isn't addressed, do you know how I can fix this problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Which browser? I test in the Chrome and with /without useHTML font size is the same.

Comment: I also use Chrome. If adjust the fontsize and switch useHTML in false, then the font will be adjusted, but with USEHTML the fontsize is still the same.